# Json conversion error expected : after key

Tags: java, json

I've been fiddling around with json conversions for the past few hours and I'm not sure why this string wouldn't convert. Can someone point me out the error?

```
{{"x" : 100, "y" : 90},{"x" : 100, "y" : 85}}
```

the error is

```
   org.json.JSONException: Expected a ':' after a key at 23 [character 24 line 1]
```

Comment: Your json is malformed.

Comment: Use `[]` not `{}` as the outer brackets, and do `new JSONArray(jsonSource)`, not `new JSONObject(jsonSource)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as this is an array the format should be

```
[
    {
        "x": 100,
        "y": 90
    },
    {
        "x": 100,
        "y": 85
    }
]
```

checkout http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: When I try to reconstruct the string with [] it says I needed to have {} for it to be a json object.

Comment: @ThaoNguyen - But it's not a JSON object, it's a JSON array.  Go to json.org and learn the difference.

Comment: @user2310289 - json.org is a better place to start.