# Creating a JSONObject from string - Expected a ':' after a key at 2770 [character 2771 line 1]

Tags: java, json

I am trying to conver a string build by StringBuilder to JSONObject. The code I am using to create a JSONObject is as follows

```
StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
//SOME CODE TO MAKE THE STRING ... ...
JSONObject returnObject = null;
        try {
            returnObject = new JSONObject(ret.toString());
        } catch (JSONException  e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return returnObject;
```

The problem is that this code is giving me following error

```
Expected a ':' after a key at 2770 [character 2771 line 1]
```

The string (Sample) I am trying to convert is as follows

```
[
{
"data":{"PHONE":"4567899874","STATE":"State1","FIRSTNAME":"Test1","EMAIL":null,"CITY":"New York","LASTNAME":"TestLast"}
},
{
"data":{"PHONE":"6457870022","STATE":"State2","FIRSTNAME":"FirstTestUpdate2","EMAIL":"last2first2@abc.com","CITY":"City2","LASTNAME":"LastTestUpdate2"}
},

{
"data":{"PHONE":"6457870003","STATE":"State3","FIRSTNAME":"FirstTestDemo3","EMAIL":"last3first3@abc.com","CITY":"City3","LASTNAME":"Last3"}
},

{"data":{"PHONE":"6457870004","STATE":"State4","FIRSTNAME":"First4","EMAIL":"last4first4@abc.com","CITY":"City4","LASTNAME":"Last4"}
},

{
"data":{"PHONE":"6457870005","STATE":"State5","FIRSTNAME":"First5","EMAIL":"last5first5@abc.com","CITY":"City5","LASTNAME":"Last5"}
},

{
"data":{"PHONE":"6457870006","STATE":"State6","FIRSTNAME":"First6","EMAIL":"last6first6@abc.com","CITY":"City6","LASTNAME":"Last6"}
},

{
"data":{"PHONE":"6845987894","STATE":"State7","FIRSTNAME":"TestFirstSA","EMAIL":null,"CITY":"City7","LASTNAME":"TestSA"}
}

]
```

When I try to convert this string using [This Online Tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) then it is parsing correctly. I saw some other questions in stackoverflow [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394748/json-conversion-error-expected-after-key) and tried to use their method but still getting error. Any suggestion what change could make the error go away.

Comment: You have to tell us what's going on around `character 2771`

Comment: @JuanMendes beat me to it but you're only showing 972 chars.

Comment:  that's why I added sample with String

Comment: But your error is at character 2771 or so in the file.  You've chopped off the cause of the error.

Comment: Yes, more strange is that in original string there are only 2769 characters

Comment: Print out the StringBuilder with quotes - i.e. `System.out.println("string is \"" + builder.toString() + "\"" );` to see if there is extra stuff at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! Lib you use is not so smart like [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson). You have to manually set that you try to parse an `JsonArray`, but not `JsonObject`.

```
String jsonArray = "[]";
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonArray);

String jsonObject = "{}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonObject);
```

Comment: When I return JSONArray object as REST API call return then it sends {"empty":false}. Do I need to convert it to something else before returning in API call?

Comment: In general case - via REST you accept and provide a JSON message. All others is you internal details.